# Change Objects Declaration Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Look at my short example:

```py
for i in range(10):
   myEntry = Entry(root)
   myEntry.pack()

myEntry.get()
```

Is there a way to access `.get()` data from the individual Entries? I thought it might be a way to change the objects declaration name inside the for loop.

I'm trying to list user inputs options by pressing a button

Comment: Why don't you use a list to store the entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep accessing what `.get()` returns for each individual `Entry` instance by storing the entry in a data structure like a list called `my_entries`  for example.

You can then access each individual entry directly through the list via indexing or loops, and call `.get()` on each entry.

```
# Create list to store entries
my_entries = []

# Store each individual entry in the list
for _ in range(10):
    myEntry = Entry(root)
    myEntry.pack()
    my_entries.append(myEntry)

# Access each entry individually
for entry in my_entries:
    print(entry.get())
```

Comment: Storing `myEntry.get()` is meaningless because it is always empty for a newly created `Entry`.  Should store the reference of the `Entry` instead: `my_entries.append(myEntry)`.